# Permuation And Combination Based Problem - Arrangements Of People In A Row Of Cinema Hall In A Particular Manner

Tags: combinatorics

There are fifteen seats in the first row of a cinema hall.The torch man has the instruction that seat number 6 must be occupied.The number of ways in which 4 seats of the first row can be alloted so that no two of them are consecutive is?

I cant understand how to eliminate the case of consecutive seats.Hints please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once seat $6$ is occupied, neither of seats $5$ or $7$ is available.  There are then three cases to consider:

Case 1: $0$ people sit in seats $1, 2, 3, 4$.  Then we must have $3$ people in seats $8$ through $15$.  Of these eight consecutive seats, five will end up unoccupied.  Let's denote these $5$ unoccupied seats with 'bars': $| | | | |$.  These bars determine $6$ spaces (one to the left, four between consecutive bars, and one to the right).  Choose $3$ of these six spaces spaces to seat a person (this is often done by inserting a star in the chosen spaces--for instance the pattern $*||*|*|||$ puts people in seats $8$, $11$, and $13$).  Thus there are $6 \choose 3$ ways to choose seats in this case.

Case 2: $1$ person sits in one of seats $1$ through $4$.  In this case a similar analysis shows that $4\cdot {7\choose 2}$ arrangements are possible.

Case 3: Similar: You try it.

The final answer does seem to come to $128$.

Comment: Exactly.You are correct.

Answer (score 0):

One person must go to seat no. 6. Remaining possible occupiable seats are 1,2,3,4,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 (i.e. $15-3=12$ remaining). These can be occupied by three persons without seating adjacently in ${}^{10}{\mathbb C}_3=120$ ways using stars and bars but these don't include the seats 4 and 8 occupied at the same time, so when seats 4,6,8 are occupied remaining 1,2,10,11,12,13,14,15 (i.e. 8 remaining ) can also be occupied. So total 128.

Comment: Sorry..but i think something is wrong with your solution.The answer given to this problem in my book by S.K Goyal is 128.So i guess if you could write out your technique in full instead of using a formula it would be better.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta sorry i forgot something, corrected.

Comment: Yes now its a good method :-)